# How to compare two Intents for equality

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Right now I have a `LinkedList` of Intents in an `IntentService` that keeps track of what Intents are enqueued by the `Service`. I'm finding that the `contains()` method is never returning true, even for identical Intents. Is there something else I have to do to compare two Intents?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(queue.contains(intent)){
                    //Never reaches here
        intent.setAction(NO_ACTION);
    }
    queue.push(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Example code for sending an Intent:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NodeIndexService.class);
    i.setAction(NodeIndexService.REFRESH);
    i.putExtra(NodeIndexService.TYPE, indexType);
    i.putExtra(NodeIndexService.RESULT_RECEIVER, receiver);
    context.startService(i);
```

Two Intents being sent one after another with this code should be identical, no? The context isn't changing, and the extras are the same as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "identical" intents? You'd need to define what it means for them to be equal, otherwise it will just do object identity.

Comment: "Identical" means the same Action, Type and Extras. I assumed if two intents were fired off with these parameters being equal on the respective Intent, equals() would return true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define your own `equals` method to meet your equality criteria, whatever they may be.

According to the [`Intent` API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) the `equals` method is defined by `Object`--simple identity.

This is more or less a standard Java fundamental; see if the class defines its own equality, if it doesn't, you need to create your own--with the caveat that whatever environment the instances are in may *also* check equality, so it pays to implement `equals` and `hashCode` *correctly*.

(If you define an `equals`, you'll want to define a `hashCode` for completeness.)

---

Your code *specifically* creates new intents--that's what `new` does.

You're creating two objects: object identity means seeing if two references refer to the *exact same object*, not if arbitrary *properties* are the same. If you want to compare based on arbitrary criteria, you need to define your own `equals` method that does the comparisons you care about.

Comment: I guess a better question would be why my Intents aren't returning true when using the equals() method. If I don't change the Action, Type, Extras, or Context, why aren't they equal?

Comment: @oneilse14 Because they're not the same instance--that's what object identity means.

Comment: so equals() compares for identity. Is there a way to compare for object equality, even if they aren't the same instance?

Comment: @oneilse14 I'm not convinced I can make it any clearer, actually: if you want to have an `equals` method that checks for something other than the object identity that `Intent` inherits from `Object`, then write it--just like both answers state.

Comment: @oneilse14 `Object.equals()` checks for object identity. If you read the API docs I linked to, you'll see that the only implementation of `equals()` that `Intent` knows about is inherited from `Object`: if you call `equals()` on an `Intent`, you're running the `equals` method of `Object`--which is object identity.

Answer (score 9):

There's a way to specifically compare intents - filterEquals():  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)

It looks like intents with the same data, category and action will be regarded as equal when using this method.

Comment: @oneilse Good, but that's not what you said in your comment--this compares more fields, and specifically *doesn't* compare extra data, which you set, and said you cared about-hence a custom equals.

Comment: @oneilse Not necessary-we don't always know what to ask; if filterEquals does what you need it to, it's the better answer, and less work-it's just different from the question/comments. If it works for you, I'd just edit/clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the intent to URI using [`Intent.toUri(0)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri(int)) and compare the resulting strings. They will only be equals if they have the same action, categories, type, flags, package, component, and extras.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
Object ob1 = (Object) intent1;
Object ob2 = (Object) intent2;

if(ob1.equals(ob2))
```

---

The above will only become true if everything about them is the same

Is there any specific parts of the intents you want to compare?

---

```
    if(intent1.getAction().equals(intent2.getAction()) && intent1.getType().equals(intent2.getType()) &&
    intent1.getExtras().equals(intent2.getExtras()))
```

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: That's what `contains` does if there's no comparator provided.

Comment: The contains() method is doing exactly this

Comment: Ahh okay, but what aspects of the intent are you wanting to compare more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Here I compare two intents using a comparator (in a unit test using FEST):

```
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;

assertThat(intentOne).usingComparator(new IntentComparator()).isEqualTo(intentTwo);

private static class IntentComparator implements Comparator<Intent> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Intent left, Intent right) {
        return left.filterEquals(right) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```