# Do intents change when they are sent through IPC?

Tags: android, ipc

I'm using a ResultReceiver to allow a service to pass data through to an activity. I'm experiencing some difficulties with comparing intents that have been sent through IPC, it looks like the objects are changing, and thus can't be compared using a standard hashcode(.equals) comparison. I've created some sample code that will reproduce the scenario:

**MyActivity.java:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver(mHandler);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("receiver", receiver);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    public class MyReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        public MyReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            Intent intent = resultData.getParcelable("intent");
            if(intent.equals(serviceIntent)) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Same intent!");
            } else {
                Log.d("TEST", "Different intents!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("receiver");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("intent", intent);
        receiver.send(100, b);
        stopSelf();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

}
```

*Don't forget to register the service in the manifest if you want to run this.*

So the intent is sent back and forth, no change is made in the process and yet my activity insists that the two references differ. What's going on here?

Comment: I would not expect the intent sent to start service and the one received by the target service to literally be the same object.  If you need to tell things apart, how about using putExtra() with a serial number or millisecond timestamp everytime you create a new one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm wondering though, why isn't the intent the same?

Answer (score 1):

The intent created by `Intent intent = resultData.getParcelable("intent")`  and `private Intent serviceIntent` are not the same object, even if they are created to contain the exact same data. The current `.equals()` function simply checks if the intents are the same object; you will have to write your own `.equals()` function to determine if the intents are the same by whatever definition fits your application. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955458/379420).